# How can I prevent iTerm2 from printing environment information on startup?

Tags: terminal, zsh, path, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I recently started using iTerm2 + Oh My Zsh to see what the hype was all about. While it's cool, I had some issues getting it to work properly. Specifically, it wasn't recognizing standard commands like `brew` or `wget` so after a quick `echo $PATH` the issue was obvious:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Definitely not my correct path. So I ran the same command from my mac terminal to grab the path I needed and then put it in my `.zshrc` file...which it seems Oh My Zsh is now president of.

```
➜  ~ cat .zshrc
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export
PATH=/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

Everything works now but every time I open iTerm2 it prints all of this info I don't want to see to stdout:

```
COLORFGBG='7;0'
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
HOME=/Users/mike
ITERM_PROFILE=zsh
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:C5A93527-6616-48F1-B2F6-752CFE16FC3C
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.19
LOGNAME=mike
OLDPWD=/Users/mike
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/mike
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.QpGCgTB8LE/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.19
TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:C5A93527-6616-48F1-B2F6-752CFE16FC3C
TMPDIR=/var/folders/mp/gqrct9qd5p919gd0_7clwypr0000gn/T/
USER=mike
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.com.googlecode.iterm2.77770830.77770836
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
➜  ~
```

How can I suppress this? Or is it a result of me not implementing my proper path correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the output of `export` invoked without arguments in zsh. There is lone `export` in your `.zshrc` just before the line that says `PATH=…`.

Maybe you meant `export PATH=…` and split this into two lines by mistake.

Usually there is no need to export `PATH` because it's already in the environment. The output of your `export` confirms that `PATH` is in the environment before you try to change its value.

Just remove the line that says `export`.

Comment: Ah...yes I split lines by mistake. Also, have never just ran export...thanks for the info about not requiring export.